# Partner and Customer community contact record visability

Tags: community, customer-community, partner-communities, sharing-rule, insufficient-privileges

I have both Partner and Customer Community users.
I have a Contact record owned by a Customer Community user which is not visible to the Partner user (which created this Contact) - an "Insufficient Privileges" error is showing.

I have a sharing rule set up which should share the Contact record with the creator, but still the Partner user is getting this error.

What am I doing wrong?
Is this a Salesforce community limitation?

Comment: Did you provide partner portal profile to access this object.

Comment: @Reshma yes, they have access to Contacts

Comment: Which licence type are you using for the Customer and Partner users as that can affect how things are shared?

Comment: @DaveHumm Customer Community license and Partner Community license

Comment: Customer Community and Partner Community licences do not use sharing rules. That means I know an answer for this I can do later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer Community licences do not use Sharing Rules, those are only available with Customer Community Plus or Partner licence types [licence types](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US).

Instead of Sharing rules you are able to use [Sharing Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_sharing_set.htm&language=en_US) to share records to Customer community members. These are set up by Setup>Build>Customize>Communities>Community Settings>Sharing Sets

[image: Community settings]

In the Sharing Sets you can set up which user profiles will use that sharing set and the objects which will be shared and the criteria for sharing. This requires External Sharing to have been set up in the OWD sharing settings and the objects set to private or public read only where the Sharing Set can be used to setup additional access to that object. This sharing can be done on standard or custom objects based on a field such as the account that a case and a customer contact are linked to as in the example below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I only see Customer Community profiles. Partner Community is not there. Does this mean that Partner users follow the regular sharing rules?

Comment: Yes, partners should follow standard sharing rules. I'll edit the answer for clarity, however it might be that the partner contacts inherit their Role for Role based sharing from the user in Saleforce that owns the record.